# Unrecognized options "type" under "nelmio_api_doc.sandbox.authentication"

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, api-doc

Having problem to call api form nelmio api doc, api work from Postman extension

config.yml

```
fos_rest:
    body_converter: 
        enabled: true
    body_listener:
        decoders:
            json: fos_rest.decoder.json
    routing_loader:
        include_format: false
        default_format: json
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    serializer:
        serialize_null: true

nelmio_api_doc:
    sandbox:
        authentication:
            delivery: http
            type: basic
        enabled: true
        accept_type: application/json
        body_format: form
```

Anybody have a solution to my problem ? Thanks !

Comment: Your conf work fine in my env!

Comment: Is i need to do any changes in other file

Comment: Fixed, actually having issue with nelmio_api_doc bundle, just updated it and it works